# Dedicated IP address from 3rd Party Services

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address

I'm using hostgator reseller panel with limit to the number of dedicated IPs. I want to use dedicated IP for each account under control panel. Unfortunately hostgator restricts me with an upsell of SSL+IP for 50$. Which i think a bit costly and packed with unnecessary SSL package which i don't want to use.

So is it possible to get dedicated IPs from another hosting service or host keeping the files hosted on different server ? or we're restricted to use dedicated IPs from the same host ?

So to frame question in this situation, is it possible to buy IP address from 3rd parties or anyone other than your host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to buy IP address from 3rd parties or anyone other than your host ?

No - upstream hosts will not route to an IP address which does not belong to *your host's* IP address assignment.

> So is it possible to get dedicated IPs from another hosting service or
>   host keeping the files hosted on different server ?

Sure, but in that case (unless there is some compelling reason to use a reverse proxy on another network) it makes more sense to simply move your hosting.

Comment: Do you think it is good choice to move hosting in my case ?

Comment: @Mahesh That depends - why do you need more IP addresses?

Comment: I want each client under cpanel to have their own IP for the account. It's for their site's SEO benefits under my single reseller account.

Comment: @Mahesh - [Do dedicated IP addresses improve SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/do-dedicated-ip-addresses-improve-seo) may be of interest in that case

Comment: Perfect. Solves for me. Hard to argue with client if their view is based on misinformation regarding IP and SEO. I'll see how it goes from here. :)