# Multidomain website SEO strategy

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do dedicated IP addresses improve SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/do-dedicated-ip-addresses-improve-seo)

There are occasionally cases in which a client owns multiple domains for his business.  For example a client may own landscaping.com, and also own newyork-landscaping.com and etc...

I have a question regarding the SEO strategy for a business in such cases, assuming that there are 50 domains for different cities, and assuming that there is unique content on every one of those 50 domains.

Is it better to have different IP addresses for each domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP addresses should be irrelevant. In terms of SEO, what matters is that the content on the sites not be cloned content. Google catches that and realizes you're running a keyword site farm.

Hopefully Google will get smarter and also penalize companies that use 50 domains to promote one company even when the sites have different content as well. ;o)

Comment: Doesn't google itself have different domains for different countries?

Comment: If you're running 50 sites all with different national TLDs, I think you'll be OK. Odds are that you'll be getting indexed by the individual national versions of Google.

Comment: They are all .com domains, I'm they belong to the same company just different branches in different cities

Comment: So what should a guy who owns 50 domains do? redirect them all to the same domain?